# Android emulator for Windows Mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-mobile

Say I want to develop applications for Android, but I only have a phone with Windows Mobile and for whatever reason I cannot switch to Android or buy a new phone.

Is there any Android emulator for Windows Mobile that would allow me to run apps on Windows Mobile 6?

P.S. I'm not interested in emulators for any other platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll probably depend on your phone.  I've got an HTC HD2, and I used to be able to boot Android off an image saved on an SD card, and then power-down the phone and boot back into Windows Mobile 6.  I eventually flashed Android right onto the phone, though, so no more dual-boot for me.

Comment: I have htc hd2. any tips how to do it?

Comment: You'll want to search XDA-developers.com -- there's a wealth of information there.  You'll find info on running from SD or flashing over permanently.  There are multiple Android builds available for this phone -- it's very popular for multi-booting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to see if there's a version of BlueStacks (http://bluestacks.com/) for Windows Mobile. There was a tablet that could run it which would allow you to run Android apps in a Windows Mobile environment.

http://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/tablets/how-to-run-android-apps-on-windows-1042650

Other than that I would say that it's probably not possible. At least not reliably and without a lot of work and messing around.

Hope this helps!